# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Astronomy Stack Exchange](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Final Results

- [To what extent are structure formations unexplained?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1664/to-what-extent-are-structure-formations-unexplained)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Do solstices and equinoxes shift over time?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1918/do-solstices-and-equinoxes-shift-over-time)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Could black holes be creators of dark matter?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1698/could-black-holes-be-creators-of-dark-matter)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What will happen to life on Earth when the Andromeda and Milky Way galaxies collide?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/what-will-happen-to-life-on-earth-when-andromeda-and-milky-way-galaxies-collide)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Adjust axis labels in ds9](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1649/adjust-axis-labels-in-ds9)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can an amateur astronomer bounce a laser off the moon?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/can-an-amateur-astronomer-bounce-a-laser-off-the-moon)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Apogalacticon and Perigalacticon](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/apogalacticon-and-perigalacticon)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Do solar systems have to evolve in a galaxy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1708/do-solar-systems-have-to-evolve-in-a-galaxy)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How would light from a blue or red star affect the way we see?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1836/how-would-light-from-a-blue-or-red-star-affect-the-way-we-see)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Would it be possible to calculate the expected frequency of impact craters of all sizes on Earth](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/would-it-be-possible-to-calculate-the-expected-frequency-of-impact-craters-of-al)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---