# Is there a 'birthday' evaluation on the table?

Tags: discussion

Congratulations to the site on one full year in beta!  I've only been using the site for about two months now, but I've been encouraged by its progress. I know from looking through Meta that there were "Site Self-Evaluations" in January and April. Given the recent milestone, I was wondering if there is any chance of a 1-year evaluation coming soon. I for one would be very interested in seeing it; the site stats on Area 51 (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40709/astronomy) clearly don't give a full picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self evaluations come every 6 months now and the [most recent was in early April](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/lets-get-critical-apr-2014-site-self-evaluation). So there should be another starting *real soon now*.

Comment: Taking a look at the queue right now. . . Should be interesting.